# Handlebars display object property dynamically by property name

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

```
{{#each modelItems as |item|}}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ item.name }}
    </td>
    {{#each selectedColumns as |extraCol|}} // line 27
        <td>
            {{ extraCol }}
            {{ item[concat '"' extraCols '"'] }} // what I tried
            {{ item[(concat '"' extraCols '"')] }}
        </td>
    {{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

In the template I have a list of `modelItems`. In the table there are some certain columns displayed but there also might be optional ones in the `selectedColumns` list.
As line 27 I am looping through `selectedColumns` to display them but no luck.
**How is it possible Handlebars to display object property dynamically by property name?**

in JS it would something like

```
foreach (items in selectedColumns) {
    console.log(item.name);
    foreach (column in selectedColumns) {
        console.log(item['"'+column+'"']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [get](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=get) helper you can access a property of an object dynamically. If you combine this with the [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) of handlebars, you can still use the [concat](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/concat?anchor=concat) helper as well.

Your code would look something like:

```
{{#each modelItems as |item|}}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ item.name }}
    </td>
    {{#each selectedColumns as |extraCol|}}
        <td>
            {{get item (concat '"' extraCol  '"')}}
        </td>
    {{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: was no more necessity of `concat`.
`{{ get item extraCol }}` does the work

Answer (score 1):

Inside the handlebars `{{` you can't write JS code, so you can't access an item inside a collection with `[]`. Instead write a helper, which returns the selected item.

I wrote an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991067/how-can-i-use-index-while-iterating-over-jsonarray-in-handlebar/49009957#49009957)

Comment: I ended up with creating helper as well.